# Compare $\arcsin (1)$ and $\tan (1)$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, inverse-function, number-comparison

> Which one is greater: $\arcsin (1)$ or $\tan (1)$?

How to find without using graph or calculator?

I tried using $\sin(\tan1)\leq1$, but how do I eliminate the possibility of an equality without using the calculator?

Comment: What method have you tried to use? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried using sin(tan1)<=1 but how do I elliminate the equality without using the calculator.

Comment: If we could establish that $\sin(1) < \cos(1) \arcsin(1) $ we would be done.

$\sin(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$,

$\cos(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}$,

$\arcsin(1)=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$

I'm not sure. And this might be a red herring but we might attempt a Cauchy product to get there.

Comment: [**How to ask a good question**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960)

Comment: @Akash Gautama Just $\sin\tan1<1$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg. And how are we establishing that?

Comment: @Mason Because always $\sin\leq1$.

Comment: Is $arcsin(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: [Wolfy says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(x)%3Dasin(x)) that the solution to
$\tan(x)=\arcsin(x)$ is
$x = 0.999906012412670 \dots$
so it seems unlikely to me that there would be an easy way of comparing the two values without actually computing them.

Comment: @HQR Yes, of course.

Comment: Which is obvious.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg  I think it may be false. Maybe $\tan 1>\frac{\pi}{2}$ but $\sin \tan1 \leq 1$

Comment: And how is it obvious?

Comment: @HQR It says that you got a contradiction in maths. $\sin$ increases on$\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Now, I see it. We don't know that $\tan1\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}).$

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg what??? $sin x \leq 1 \forall x\in \mathbb R$

Comment: @HQR Yes. You did not know?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg So we could not judge $tan(1)$ by this inequality

Comment: Very nice problem! Now, good people will come and will close this topic.

Answer (score 14):

One can write:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^21}} = \cos1 = 1 - 2\sin^2\frac{1}{2} > \frac{17639}{32768},
$$
because
$$
\sin\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^3\cdot3!} + \frac{1}{2^5\cdot5!} = \frac{1920 - 80 + 1}{3840} < \frac{1845}{3840} = \frac{123}{256}.
$$
On the other hand, using Archimedes's lower bound, $\pi > 3\tfrac{10}{71}$:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\sin^{-1}1\right)^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{223}{142}\right)^2}} = \frac{142}{\sqrt{69893}} < \frac{142}{\sqrt{69696}} = \frac{142}{264} = \frac{71}{132}.
$$
So, one can prove that $\tan1 < \sin^{-1}1$ by proving that:
$$
\frac{17639}{32768} > \frac{71}{132},
$$
which simplifies to $33 \times 17639 > 71 \times 8192$, that is, $582087 > 581632$ - which is true.

Comment: Nice series acceleration trick in passing to the half-angle formula. Also a nice use of a rigorous rational bound for $\pi$. +1.

Comment: Simplifying slightly:
$$
\cos1 > \frac{17639}{32768} > \frac{17632}{32768} =
\frac{551}{1024} > \frac{71}{132},
$$
because $33 \times 551 > 71 \times 256$, i.e. $18183 > 18176$.

Comment: **N.B.** There is a much better answer - to essentially the same question - [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3133073/213690).

Answer (score 10):

**Problem with the Approach in the Question**

Note that $\sin(\tan(1))\lt1$ does not insure that $\tan(1)\lt\arcsin(1)$ because $\arcsin(\sin(\tan(1)))\ne\tan(1)$ if $\tan(1)\gt\frac\pi2$.

---

**Another Approach**

Let $\alpha=\arctan\left(\frac\pi2\right)$. Since $\tan(\alpha)=\frac\pi2\lt\sqrt3=\tan\left(\frac\pi3\right)$, we know that $\alpha\lt\frac\pi3$.

Furthermore,
$$
\frac\pi3-\alpha\le\tan\left(\frac\pi3-\alpha\right)=\frac{\sqrt3-\frac\pi2}{1+\sqrt3\frac\pi2}\tag1
$$
Thus, using the underestimate $\frac{333}{106}$ for $\pi$ and the overestimate $\frac{26}{15}$ for $\sqrt3$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha
&\ge\frac\pi3-\frac{\sqrt3-\frac\pi2}{1+\sqrt3\frac\pi2}\\
&\ge\frac{111}{106}-\frac{\frac{26}{15}-\frac{333}{212}}{1+\frac{26}{15}\cdot\frac{333}{212}}\\
&=\frac{314804}{313707}\\[9pt]
&\gt1\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\tan(1)\lt\tan(\alpha)=\arcsin(1)}\tag3
$$

---

**A Note About The Inequality**

In the inequality $(2)$, we use the fact that $\frac{a-b}{1+ab}$ is increasing in $a$ and decreasing in $b$, for $a,b\ge0$. One way to see this is to recall that this expression came from
$$
\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)-\tan(\beta)}{1+\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}
$$
and let $\alpha=\arctan(a)$ and $\beta=\arctan(b)$. Since $\alpha,\beta\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right)$, we know that $\alpha-\beta\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$, in which interval, $\tan$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Why the downvote? If it is about the estimated values, $\frac{333}{106}$ is a fairly well known continued fraction under-estimate for $\pi$ and $\frac{26}{15}\gt\sqrt3$ can be verified by noting that $26^2=676\gt675=3\cdot15^2$.

Answer (score 5):

I try to calculate $\tan 1 <1.57<\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\tan x =x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}+\frac{62x^9}{2835}+o(x^9)$

$|\tan x-x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}+\frac{62x^9}{2835}|<\frac{62x^9}{2835},x\in[0,1]$

So:$\tan 1<1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{15}+\frac{17}{315}+\frac{62}{2835}+\frac{62}{2835}<1.565<1.57<\frac{\pi}{2}=\arcsin 1$

Edits:
It seems that there just need four terms by under  @Ian reminding

$\tan x =x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}+\frac{62\xi^9}{2835},\xi\in[0,1]$

$\tan 1<1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{15}+\frac{17}{315}+\frac{62}{2835}<1.56<1.57<\frac{\pi}{2}=\arcsin 1$

Comment: Technically you need to be a bit more careful about estimating the remainder term.

Comment: I am checking it. @Michael Rozenberg

Comment: @Ian  I use lagrange remainder to control it.

Comment: That isn't the correct Lagrange remainder formula, though. The correct bound (in view of monotonicity properties of the derivatives of $\tan$) would be to take the next Taylor term and plug in $x=1$.

Comment: @Ian yes, you are right , but it would be less than $\frac{62}{2835}$. So I use  $\frac{62}{2835}$ avoiding more calculation.

Comment: The following term it's $\frac{1382x^{11}}{1559225}$ and we can end it. But this solution is not so nice.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg  Yes, it will be difficult.

Comment: I think you put the $\xi$ in the wrong spot, the issue is finding a derivative which is not too big (relative to the $n!$ that it is divided by) at $1$. For example, the leading order estimate only gives $\tan(1) \leq \sec^2(1)$ which isn't good enough, then the next one gives $\tan(1) \leq 1+\sec^2(1) \tan(1)$ which is also not good enough, etc.

Comment: Perhaps a better idea is to do the expansion at $\pi/4$ or $\pi/3$ instead.

Comment: @Ian Well, maybe you have better method to estimate it. I look up my book and I am sure it would work…… so I could not understand "I think you put the $\xi$ in the wrong spot"………

Comment: @HQR The point is that the $\xi$ goes into the evaluation of the derivative. In this non-alternating situation you do not have the freedom to evaluate the derivative at $0$, you are forced to evaluate it at the worst possible point which in this case is $\xi=1$. For $\tan$ this is very bad because the derivatives of $\tan$ grow rather fast, even though they do eventually die down (as we know from analyticity).

Comment: I notice with a calculator that the bound $\tan(1) \leq \sqrt{3}+\sec^2(1)(1-\pi/3)$ is good enough to get the result, but I don't know how much tedious grinding of approximation of $\sqrt{3},\sec(1)$ and $\pi$ would be required to prove that. (Presumably quite a bit, because this number is less than $5 \cdot 10^{-4}$ away from $\pi/2$...)

Answer (score 5):

$\arcsin(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ while from the Weierstrass product for the cosine function we have
$$ \tan(1) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{8}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2-4 }=2\sum_{n\geq 0}\left[\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi-2}-\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi+2}\right]$$
such that an effective integral representation of $\tan(1)$ through an almost-Gaussian integral is
$$\tan(1)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sinh(2x)}{\sinh(\pi x)}\,dx.$$
As an alternative, by expanding $\frac{8}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2-4}$ as a geometric series we get
$$ \tan(1) = 2 \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(4^m-1)\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}} $$
which is equivalent to the previous integral representation via $\zeta(2m)=\frac{1}{(2m-1)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2m-1}}{e^z-1}\,dz$.
In order to prove that $\tan(1)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ it is enough to show that $\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)<\frac{\pi}{2+\sqrt{\pi^2+4}}$, since $\tan(2z)=\frac{2\tan z}{1-\tan^2 z}$. $\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ has a fast-convergent series representation
$$ \tan\left(\tfrac12\right)=4\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}}\left(1-\frac{1}{4^m}\right) $$
which allows to state
$$ \tan\left(\tfrac12\right) < 4\sum_{m= 1}^{3}\frac{\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}}\left(1-\frac{1}{4^m}\right)+4\,\zeta(8)\sum_{m \geq 4}\frac{1}{\pi^{2m}}\left(1-\frac{1}{4^m}\right)$$
or
$$ \tan\left(\tfrac12\right)<\frac{131}{240}+\frac{\pi ^2 \left(85 \pi^2-21\right)}{50400 \left(\pi^2-1\right) \left(4 \pi^2-1\right)}$$
(this is *extremely* accurate). The proof is finished by exploiting $\frac{227}{23}<\pi^2<\frac{79}{8}$ which follows from the study of the Beuker-like integrals
$$ \iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{x^m(1-x)^m y^n (1-y)^n}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy.$$

---

An alternative approach. The [Shafer-Fink inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753) gives that for any $x\in(0,3/2)$
$$ \tan(x) < \frac{3x+2x\sqrt{9-3x^2}}{9-4x^2} $$
holds, so by the duplication formula for the tangent function the sharper inequality
$$ \tan(x) < \frac{4 x\left(9-x^2\right) \left(3+\sqrt{36-3 x^2}\right)}{324-117 x^2+7 x^4-6 x^2 \sqrt{36-3 x^2}} $$
holds too. This gives
$$ \tan(1) < \frac{32 \left(3+\sqrt{33}\right)}{214-6 \sqrt{33}}=\frac{4}{697} \left(105+29 \sqrt{33}\right) $$
so it is enough to show that $\pi>\frac{32(3+\sqrt{33})}{107-3\sqrt{33}}$, which is a pretty loose inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method.  The only real disadvantage is that it requires calculating $e^{-1}$ in decimal form, but only two digits are needed, so this can be done by hand easily.  It does not require using very large fractions or remembering the series for $\tan(x)$.

As in another answers, we want to find an upper bound for $\sin(1)$ and a lower bound for $\cos(1)$ so that we can show that $\tan(1) < \frac{\pi}{2} = \sin^{-1}(1)$.  From there, given the monotonicity of $\sin^{-1}(x)$, the result follows easily.

$\sin(1)$ can be expanded as

$$ \sin(1) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \sin(1) + \sinh(1) \right] + \frac{1}{2} \left[ \sin(1) - \sinh(1) \right] $$

The first half represents the positive terms in the Maclaurin series for $\sin$, and the second term represents the negative terms.  On the second half, just keep the first term:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left[ \sin(1) - \sinh(1) \right] = - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(4n+3)!} \le -\frac{1}{6} $$

Plugging this into the first equation and solving for $\sin(1)$ above, we get

$$ \begin{align} \sin(1) &\le \sinh(1) - \frac{1}{3} \\ &= \frac{e-e^{-1}}{2} - \frac{1}{3} \\ &\le \frac{2.72 - 0.36}{2} - 0.333 \\ &= 0.847 \end{align} $$

Now consider the Maclaurin series for $\cos(1)$.  The terms are alternating and decrease in magnitude, so for a lower bound, we can terminate after any negative term.  Keep the first four terms:

$$ \begin{align} \cos(1) & \ge 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{720} \\ & \ge 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \left( \frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{600} \right) \\ & = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{25} \\ &= 1 - 0.5 + 0.04 \\ & = 0.54 \end{align} $$

This gives us
$$ \tan(1) \le \frac{0.847}{0.54} < 1.57 < \frac{\pi}{2} = \sin^{-1}(1) $$

Of course, it would have taken me a really long time to come up with this without the use of a calculator for exploration.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^4\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{(2i+1)}\left(\frac1x\right)^{2i+1}$ and $f(x)=\tan^{-1}x-\left(\frac\pi2+g(x)\right)$. We then have the rather delightful derivatives $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{x^{10}(x^2+1)}$ and $g'(x)=\frac{x^{10}+1}{x^{10}(x^2+1)}$, which tells us that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are respectively decreasing and increasing. Then, since $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$, we have that $f(x)>0$. As $f\left(\frac\pi2\right)>0$, we have

$$\tan^{-1}\frac\pi2>\frac\pi2+\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^4\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{(2i+1)}\left(\frac2\pi\right)^{2i+1}}_{g(\pi/2)}$$

As $g(x)$ is increasing, we have $g(\pi/2)>g(3.14/2)$. Hence, we may put this all together to say

$$\begin{aligned}\tan^{-1}\frac\pi2&>\frac{3.14}{2}+\sum_{i=0}^4\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{(2i+1)}\left(\frac2{3.14}\right)^{2i+1}\\\text{RHS}&=\frac{314}{200}-\frac{200}{314}+\ldots-\frac19\left(\frac{200}{314}\right)^9\\&=1.00238\end{aligned}$$

Finally, as $\tan x$ is increasing, we have that $\frac\pi2>\tan(1.00238)>\tan(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\arcsin1=\pi/2$, it suffices to show $2\sin1\lt\pi\cos1$, in order to conclude that $\tan1\lt\arcsin1$.

We have

$$2\sin1=2\left(1-{1\over6}+{1\over120}-\cdots \right)\lt2\left(1-{1\over6}+{1\over120}\right)={101\over60}$$

While

$$\pi\cos1=\pi\left(1-{1\over2}+{1\over24}-{1\over720}+\cdots \right)\gt\pi\left(1-{1\over2}+{1\over24}-{1\over720}\right)={389\over720}\pi$$

so it suffices to note that $\pi\gt1212/389\approx3.1317829$. To be a little less calculator-dependent, note that

$${1212\over389}\lt{1215\over387}={135\over43}\lt{314\over100}=3.14\lt\pi$$

since $135\cdot100=13500\lt13502=314\cdot43$. (And if desired, even this arithmetic can be further simplified by noting that ${135\over43}=3+{6\over43}$ and ${314\over100}=3+{7\over50}$, with ${6\over43}\lt{7\over50}$ since $6\cdot50=300\lt301=7\cdot43$.)