# How do I prove $\tan1 < \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that the equation
$$\sin x \sin({\sin x}) = \frac{\pi}{2} \cos({\sin x})$$
has no real solutions.

Let $t=\sin x$, $-1\leq t\leq 1$. Then the expression above is equvalent to $t\sin t = \frac{\pi}{2} \cos t$. As the function $f(t)=t\sin t - \frac{\pi}{2} \cos t$ is even, and $t=0$ is not a solution, I have to prove that $f(t)$ has no positive roots ($t>0$).  So, for the left side $0<t\leq 1$ and $0<\sin t\leq \sin1$, then $t\sin t\leq \sin1$. For the right side $\cos t\geq \cos1$, so $\frac{\pi}{2} \cos t\geq \frac{\pi}{2} \cos1$. The objective is to prove that $\sin1<\frac{\pi}{2} \cos1$, or, equivalently, $\tan1 < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I don't know how to approach this inequality. The arguments and the values are mixed up.

Comment: Well, they're [close](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%2F2-tan(1))

Comment: **Welcome** to the site !

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I don't agree with close votes on a question like this.  It's a perfectly reasonable math question, and one that is likely to be well beyond the capabilities of a beginner, as your answer shows.  In fact, a beginner is likely to have no idea how to start.  (Also, I would never vote to close a question from new contributor, unless it was offensive in some way.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley it's a new trend on MSE that some people in the CRUDE chatroom think it's OK to delete others' posts just because the question had been closed before. Do post the issue on meta, but don't raise your expectations high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the Taylor series and alternating series theorem to say
$$\sin 1 \lt 1-\frac 1{3!}+\frac 1{5!}=\frac {101}{120}\\
\cos 1 \gt 1-\frac 1{2!}+\frac 1{4!}-\frac 1{6!}=1-\frac 12+\frac 1{24}-\frac 1{720}=\frac{389}{720}\\
\tan 1=\frac {\sin 1}{\cos 1} \lt \frac {606}{389} \lt 1.56 \lt \frac {\pi}2$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a Community Wiki repost of one of several deleted answers to a deleted question from last year: [Compare $\arcsin (1)$ and $\tan (1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877251).

[I have taken this opportunity to incorporate a simplification - but only a slight one - I made later in a comment.]

I would be pleased if we were allowed to revisit the other deleted answers, too.

---

One can write:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^21}} = \cos1 = 1 - 2\sin^2\frac{1}{2} >
\frac{17639}{32768} > \frac{17632}{32768} =
\frac{551}{1024},
$$
because
$$
\sin\frac{1}{2} <
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^3\cdot3!} + \frac{1}{2^5\cdot5!} =
\frac{1920 - 80 + 1}{3840} < \frac{1845}{3840} = \frac{123}{256}.
$$
On the other hand, using Archimedes's lower bound,
$\pi > 3\tfrac{10}{71}$:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\sin^{-1}1\right)^2}} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}} <
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{223}{142}\right)^2}} =
\frac{142}{\sqrt{69893}} <
\frac{142}{\sqrt{69696}} =
\frac{142}{264} = \frac{71}{132}.
$$
So, one can prove that $\tan1 < \sin^{-1}1$ by proving that:
$$
\frac{551}{1024} > \frac{71}{132},
$$
which simplifies to $33 \times 551 > 71 \times 256$, that is,
$18183 > 18176$ - which is true.

Comment: [Repost of most of a deleted comment.] Honestly, having seen Ross Millikan's exemplary simple answer to the present question, I've lost interest in trying to revive last year's question and answers. I admit to a mild, sneaky curiosity as to whether everybody else made as much unnecessary fuss in their answers as I did in mine [...]